# Changing path to current working directory in zsh prompt

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to modify an existing zsh prompt to work with zsh 5.0 and 4.3 because those the versions the systems that I use. **How would I make a zsh-script be aware of the current working directory instead of the directory that the file is in?**

For context,

This is a function in the script that checks if we're currently in a git directory and adds to the prompt if we are:

```
# Git status.
# Collect indicators, git branch and pring string.
spaceship_git_status() {
  [[ $SPACESHIP_GIT_SHOW == false ]] && return

  # Check if the current directory is in a Git repository.
  command git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree &>/dev/null || return

  # Check if the current directory is in .git before running git checks.
  if [[ "$(git rev-parse --is-inside-git-dir 2> /dev/null)" == 'false' ]]; then
    # Ensure the index is up to date.
    git update-index --really-refresh -q &>/dev/null

    # String of indicators
    local indicators=''

    indicators+="$(spaceship_git_uncomitted)"
    indicators+="$(spaceship_git_unstaged)"
    indicators+="$(spaceship_git_untracked)"
    indicators+="$(spaceship_git_stashed)"
    indicators+="$(spaceship_git_unpushed_unpulled)"

    [ -n "${indicators}" ] && indicators=" [${indicators}]";

    echo -n " %Bon%b "
    echo -n "%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}"
    echo -n "$(git_current_branch)"
    echo -n "%{$reset_color%}"
    echo -n "%{$fg_bold[red]%}"
    echo -n "$indicators"
    echo -n "%{$reset_color%}"
  fi
}
```

However, based on my debugging, it appears that the function always believes that it is in the directory from which the script was sourced. In other words, as I change directory, the script continues to reference the directory where the script is located.

The `spaceship_git_status` function is called here:

```
# Build prompt line
spaceship_build_prompt() {
  spaceship_host
  spaceship_current_dir
  spaceship_git_status
  spaceship_nvm_status
  spaceship_ruby_version
  spaceship_venv_status
}
```

And this is the `PROMPT` environment variable is:

```
# Compose PROMPT
PROMPT=''
[[ $SPACESHIP_PROMPT_ADD_NEWLINE == true ]] && PROMPT="$PROMPT$NEWLINE"
PROMPT="$PROMPT $(spaceship_build_prompt) "
[[ $SPACESHIP_PROMPT_SEPARATE_LINE == true ]] && PROMPT="$PROMPT$NEWLINE"
PROMPT="$PROMPT $(spaceship_return_status) "
```

I think this is an issue with zsh versions < 5.2 because the prompt renders fine on my other computer with 5.2.

Full code: https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-zsh-theme/blob/master/spaceship.zsh